# How to check if a given date is in the 1st or 2nd week, or whatever?

Tags: php, mysql, date, pdo

I'm writing an event panel and I need to generate a list of artists who play on a given day or week. I have already done generating individual tables with events and checking if the start and end dates are longer than 1 week and generating tables with weeks. And I have no idea how to check in order to generate a list of days with artists until a given week, having only the duration of the event and the date when a particular artist is playing

**PHP Functions:**

```
function eventWeeks($dateOne, $dateTwo){
    //Create a DateTime object for the first date.
    $firstDate = new DateTime($dateOne);
    //Create a DateTime object for the second date.
    $secondDate = new DateTime($dateTwo);
    //Get the difference between the two dates in days.
    $differenceInDays = $firstDate->diff($secondDate)->days;
    //Divide the days by 7
    $differenceInWeeks = $differenceInDays / 7;
    //Round down with floor and return the difference in weeks.
    return round($differenceInWeeks, 1);
}
function getWeeksCount($dateOne, $dateTwo){
    //Create a DateTime object for the first date.
    $firstDate = new DateTime($dateOne);
    //Create a DateTime object for the second date.
    $secondDate = new DateTime($dateTwo);
    //Get the difference between the two dates in days.
    $differenceInDays = $firstDate->diff($secondDate)->days;
    //Divide the days by 7
    $differenceInWeeks = $differenceInDays / 7;
    //Round down with floor and return the difference in weeks.
    return floor($differenceInWeeks);
}
```

**PHP Code:**

```
$sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM events");
$events = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
    foreach($events as $event){
        $event_name = $event['name'];
        echo '<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i>
        <span class="card-title">'.$event_name.' - Timetable</span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">';
        $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM lineup l JOIN events e ON e.name=l.event WHERE e.name='$event_name' ORDER BY l.artist ASC");
        $artists = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($sql->rowCount()===0){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-info">No Artists in the Database! Chose an Artist using the Form above!</div>';
        }else{
            $event_startDate = $event['start-date'];
            $event_endDate = $event['end-date'];
            if(eventWeeks($event_startDate, $event_endDate) > 1){
                for($i = 0;$i <= getWeeksCount($event_startDate, $event_endDate); $i++){
                    $weeks = $i;
                    echo '<div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                        <span class="card-title">WEEK '.++$weeks.'</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">';
                    foreach($artists as $artist){
                        if(($artist['timetable_date'] >= $event_startDate) && ($artist['timetable_date'] <= $event_endDate)){
                            echo $artist['timetable_date'];
                        }
                    }
                    echo '</div>
                    </div>';
                }               
                echo 'WEEK';
            }else{
                echo 'NORMAL';
            }
        }

        echo '</div>
        </div>';
    }
}
```

**Screen:**
[image: Render Template]

Comment: The beauty of pdo is that it allows for prepared and bound/executed queries. It seems tragic to overlook this boon.

Comment: not clear to me if this is primarily a php question or a mysql question. what does this mean: "generate a list of days with artists until a given week"

Comment: selecting all records from a table and then doing a second query for each record seems like a bad idea, but it's not clear to me what your code is trying to do and how that differs from what you want it to do

Comment: @ysth I added a screen showing how it should look where there are no subcategories, it means that the event is simply for example 1 day or less than a week

Comment: consider using submethods for deeper logic levels to make your code understandable - mostly if you split up code, the problems resolve ...